# PhantomJS getScreenshot() gets only part of page

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

How can I render the whole page? The saved image only has the last few elements I've worked with, not the whole page.

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
_driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);

// do stuff
// ........
_driver.FindElement(By.Name("iFirstName"), 10)     .SendKeys("PhantomJS Firstname");
// do stuff
// ........

((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("saved\\screencap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1366, 2732);
```